# JS .click() trigger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, dropzone

I'm using `dropzone.js` to upload files.

I have a `dropzone` button `#btn` and input field `#input`.

This code is working:

```
$('#input').on('input', function() {
    $("#btn").click();
});
```

But when I use `$("#btn").click();` in other part, for example below, it's not working and I have no errors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click();
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: try to use `$("#btn").trigger("click");`

Comment: Is `#btn` dynamically created? If so then it probably hasn't been added to the document when the ready event has been triggered. The same goes with the event click handler, if it hasn't been set by the time your ready event is triggered it won't work.

Comment: this works, but dropzone upload does not apear. added both in document ready

$("#btn").click(function(){
        alert("Hello");
        console.log("Hello");
    });

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to simulate the `click` event so you need to use `trigger()` with `click` event like

`$("#btn").trigger("click")`

Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Note: [calling `click()` and other event methods with no arguments calls `trigger(eventName)` internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/event/alias.js#L19)

Answer (score 0):

click() its vanila javascript function that mean trigger type.

```
element.on.click(){
  doSomthing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone is probably taking some time to initialize by the same document.ready event. So give it a time. I would try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#btn").trigger("click");
  }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
});
```

or instead of id give class name

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#btn').click( function() {
 console.log('success');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value='upload' id='btn'>
 Upload
</button>
```